# Mockito and CDI bean injection, does @InjectMocks call @PostConstruct?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, cdi, postconstruct

I have this code:

```
class Patient {

  @Inject Syringe syringe;

  @PostConstruct
  void sayThankyouDoc() {

    System.out.println("That hurt like crazy!");

  }

}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class TestCase {

  @Mock
  Syringe siringeMock;

  @InjectMocks
  Patient patient;

  //...

}
```

I expected Mockito to call PostConstruct, but I had to add:

```
@Before
public void simulate_post_construct() throws Exception {
    Method postConstruct = Patient.class.getDeclaredMethod("sayThankyouDoc", null);
    postConstruct.setAccessible(true);
    postConstruct.invoke(patient);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A different design that is both more readable and easier to test, is to not use `@PostConstruct` at all, and use constructor injection instead of field injection

Comment: @geoand but what _is_ constructor injection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although not a direct answer to your question, however I suggest that you move away from field injection and use constructor injection instead (makes code more readable and testable).

Your code would look like:

```
class Patient {

  private final Syringe syringe;

  @Inject
  public Patient(Syringe syringe) {
    System.out.println("That hurt like crazy!");
  }

}
```

Then your test would simply be:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class TestCase {

  @Mock
  Syringe siringeMock;

  Patient patient;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
     patient = new Patient(siringeMock);
  }

}
```

**Update**

As suggested by [Erik-Karl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454556/eric-karl) in the comments, you could use `@InjectMocks` to get rid of the setup method. The solution works because Mockito will use the appropriate constructor injection (as described [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html)).
The code would then look like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class TestCase {

  @Mock
  Syringe siringeMock;

  @InjectMocks
  Patient patient;

}
```

Comment: Not only is it more testable, but you get some thread-safety guarantees by having the fields be final. Note that even with the above code, you would need to manually call your `@PostConstruct` method

Comment: Might be a bit old but I just want to add: InjectMock will inject through constructor if available. So here, you would only have to annotate the Patient with InjectMock and could get rid of the setup method.

Comment: @Eric-Karl Very useful! Thanks! I updated the answer with your suggestion

Comment: someone pls edit the question with the answer: No.